# Неправильная компиляция из Unity в WebGL

Tags: unity3d, webgl

Есть готовый Open Source проект, на примере которого мне нужно сделать генерацию окружения. При компиляции этого проекта в WebGL не срабатывает сама генерация. На первой картинке - как оно выглядит, на второй - как должно выглядеть. В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить?

Репозиторий проекта: https://github.com/maxilevi/project-skylines

[image: Как оно выглядит]

[image: Как должно]

Comment: Может дело не в генерации, а в шейдерах?

Comment: А как можно это исправить? Изменение на другие шейдеры не помогло